# Is It Possible to Comment Out HTML Code in a Wordpress Post?

Tags: wordpress, editor, comments, html-entities

Sometimes I need to inject some raw HTML code into a Wordpress post, and sometimes I need to comment out a chunk of that code.!

With a plain text editor, I can just use `<!--  Comment  -->` around the chunk I want to hide.

But when I try this in a WP post, it does hide the code but I still see the "closing comment tag" `-->`.

What's the right way, if possible, to comment out code in a WP post?

Thanks!

Comment: This question probably belongs on [superuser](http://superuser.com) or [webapps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com).

Comment: i think he means placing comments in a post via wp admin does not convert the entities properly.

Comment: Right..HTML view via wp admin...

Comment: use the code tag to show raw html here, or you can use the `\`` code a small peice

Comment: In 2022 this is what worked for me- I nested the comment tag inside a div tag:

<div><!-- comment --></div>

Answer (score 28):

wpautop() contains a bug that breaks comments containing HTML code. An easy workaround is to add a second opening HTML comment tag just before the closing - this tricks WordPress into working like you would expect it to. see http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/2691

This will work in WordPress:

```
<!-- <div class="book floatleft"><a href="#">
<img src="http://www.myreallycoolsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/button.png" alt="" />
</a></div> <!-- -->
```

This will not work in WordPress:

```
<!-- <div class="book floatleft"><a href="#">
<img src="http://www.myreallycoolsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/button.png" alt="" />
</a></div> -->
```

Comment: I like this solution because you don't have to rely on CSS to make it work, you don't have to mess with default or added filters, you don't have to turn off or avoid the visual editor, and it will work if you move your content somewhere else. Cheers.

Comment: A major problem with this is that it adds a line break after the comment.

Comment: lol after waiting 11 years this bug is slated for a fix in version 4.9 of Wordpress. I wouldn't hold your breath.

Answer (score 10):

Use a hidden div block

like this:

```
<div style="display: none;">

...comment...

</div>
```

works like a charm

Comment: The problem with this solution is that bots will still index the content within the `<div>`.

Comment: From a semantically point of view is not acceptable as solution. An HTML comment is not part of the page content (like other undisplayed elements such collapsables, accordions, panels, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of typeing `<!--Comment-->` in the editor for your post, Make sure you place the comment tag inside the raw html editor.

[image]
<sub>(source: [headwaythemes.com](http://headwaythemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/html_editor.jpg))</sub>

Also use a DOM Inspector to make sure that th `-->` closing tag is actually coming form the post itself.

Another Tip, before you publish the article, hit the `Close Tags` button to make sure that it validates your html better.

Comment: I appreciate all the advice.  @RobertPitt - Firebug seemed to show that the "-->" got translated to "--&gt;"  I tried "close tags" but it didn't seem to help.  @h3r2on - I'm using 2.9.2 (can't upgrade to 3 because I've got lots of custom code and not enough time or patience to test/fix)

Comment: i know that > gets converted to its enties, but i jsut tested on the latest wordpress version and its ok :/

Answer (score 1):

You could try one of the following plugins which preserves code formatting within the html editor:

- **TRUEedit Plugin**
- **WP Super Edit**
- **ps-disable-auto-formatting**
- **Unfiltered MU** (multisite only)

I believe most of these plugins removes the wptexturize filter that WordPress uses which replaces characters and patterns (which messes up some shortcodes and html).

If your using 'Deans FCKEditor' or 'Foliopress WYSIWYG' that could be the problem since they convert quotes to html quotes, add paragraph markup, mess up shortcodes, and do some other html character replacement.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet should do what you're looking for.

```
// Add the unfiltered_html capability back in to WordPress 3.0 multisite.
function um_unfilter_multisite( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {
if ( $cap == 'unfiltered_html' ) {
    unset( $caps );
    $caps[] = $cap;
}
return $caps;
}
add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'um_unfilter_multisite', 10, 4 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!-- Comment --!>
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
&lt;!&#45;&#45;<br />
... commented out stuff ...<br >
&lt;&#45;&#45;&gt;
```

but beware the HTML break tag WordPress will throw in at the end of the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Like jharrel suggested, this works just fine:

```
<!-- content <!-- -->
```